# how to fixthe scrollbar always at the bottom of a div.....?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

When loading the page the scrollbar must be at the bottom.. This is My HtmlFiles

```
<div ng-controller="ConversationController as value">
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="main-box clearfix">
                    <header class="main-box-header clearfix">
                        <h2>Conversation...</h2>
                    </header>  
                    <form id="scroll">                      
                    <div class="main-box-body clearfix">
                        <div class="conversation-wrapper"when-scrolled="more()"schroll-bottom="value"id="scrolled">
                            <div class="conversation-content">
                                <span ng-repeat="message in value">
                                    <div class="conversation-item item-left clearfix"
                                        ng-show="{{message.whoSendTheMessage.userId!=loggedUser}}">
                                        <div class="conversation-user">
                                            <img src="lib/app/img/user.jpg" style="width: 50px;" alt="">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="conversation-body">
                                            <div class="name">{{message.whoSendTheMessage.firstName}}&nbsp;{{message.whoSendTheMessage.lastName}}</div>
                                            <div class="time hidden-xs">{{message.sendDate |
                                                date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss '}}</div>
                                            <div class="text">{{message.content}}</div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="conversation-item item-right clearfix"
                                        ng-show="{{message.whoSendTheMessage.userId==loggedUser}}">
                                        <div class="conversation-user">
                                            <img src="lib/app/img/user.jpg" style="width: 50px;" alt="">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="conversation-body">
                                            <div class="name">{{message.whoSendTheMessage.firstName}}&nbsp;{{message.whoSendTheMessage.lastName}}</div>
                                            <div class="time hidden-xs">{{message.sendDate |
                                                date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss '}}</div>
                                            <div class="text">{{message.content}}</div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </form> 
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="conversation-new-message message-box">
                                    <form>
                                        <div class="form-group row">
                                            <textarea class="form-control pull-left" rows="2" name="messagebox"
                                                ng-model="message.content" placeholder="Enter your message..."></textarea>
                                            <button type="submit" ng-click="saveMessage();"
                                                class="btn btn-success  fa fa-paper-plane message-button"></button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
        </div>
```

This is controller Page.. When loading the index page the scrollbar must be at the bottom.....

```
 define([ "angular", "app","atmosphere", "services/ajaxService", "services/userservice","services/context-service","services/atmosphere-service", "factory/atmosphere-factory" ],
                function(angular, app, atmosphere) {
                var conversationController = app.controller("ConversationController",
                            ["$log","$scope","AjaxService","UserService","$window","ContextService","$timeout","AtmosphereService","AtmosphereFactory",
                        function($log, $scope, ajaxService, UserService, $window, contextService,$timeout,AtmosphereService,AtmosphereFactory) {
                            console.log("conversation controller");
                            var self = $scope; 
                            self.pageNo = -1;
                            self.pageSize = 10;
                            self.isMore = true;
                            var url ="";
                            $scope.value= [];
                            var messageBelongTo=0;
                            self.message = {
                                    "content" : "",
                                    "complexContent" : {
                                        "header" : "Sample",
                                        "image" : "sample",
                                        "metaData" : "image"
                                    },
                                    "contentType" : "TEXT",
                                    "sendDate" : null,
                                    "whenDeliveredInServer" : null,
                                    "whoSendTheMessage" : {
                                        "userId" : 0
                                    },
                                    "messageBelongTo" : {
                                        "conversationId" : 0
                                    } 
                                };

                            self.loggedUser = contextService.userData.userId;
                             self.more = function() { 
                                 if (!self.isMore) {
                                        return;
                                    }
                                    self.pageNo += 1;
                                console.log("Init conversation controller"); 
                                messageBelongTo=contextService.selectedConversationId; 
                                var check=null; 
                                if(contextService.backUrl=='inbox'){ 
                                    check = contextService.getUrl("messagelist");
                                    messageBelongTo=contextService.selectedConversationId;
                                    check += "/" +messageBelongTo + '/' + self.pageNo + '/' + self.pageSize;
                                } 
                                else{  
                                    check = contextService.getUrl("contactmessagelist");
                                    console.log("userId",contextService.userData.userId);
                                    console.log("contactId",contextService.selectedContact);
                                    check +="/"+contextService.userData.userId+ '/' + self.pageNo + '/' + self.pageSize +"?contactId=" +contextService.selectedContact;
                                }
                                ajaxService.get({
                                    url : check,
                                         success : function(data) {  
                                        if( data.responseSuccess){  
                                            $log.log("Success!", angular.fromJson(data.result));
                                            if($scope.value.length !=0){
                                                messageBelongTo= $scope.value[0]['messageBelongTo']['conversationId'];
                                            } 
                                            console.log('Conversatio n Id is'+messageBelongTo);
                                            if (data.result.length === 0) {
                                                self.isMore = false;
                                            }
                                            for (var i = 0; i < data.result.length; i++) {
                                                $scope.value.push(data.result[i]);
                                            }
                                            if($scope.value.length !=0){
                                                messageBelongTo= $scope.value[0]['messageBelongTo']['conversationId'];
                                            } 

                                            console.log('Conversatio n Id is'+messageBelongTo);
                                            $scope.$apply();          
                                        } 
                                        else if( data.responseError){
                                            $scope.value = []; 
                                        } 
                                        $scope.isAjax = false;
                                        $scope.$apply();
                                        $timeout(function(){
                                            //$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, "fast"); 
                                        //$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 150000 }, 2000);
                                         //angular.element(".conversation-wrapper").scrollTop(angular.element(".conversation-wrapper")[0].scrollHeight);
                                        },200); 

                                    },
                                    error : function(data) {
                                        $log.log("Error: ", data);
                                        $scope.isAjax = false;
                                        $scope.$apply();
                                    }
                                });
                            };
                             self.more();
                            $scope.saveMessage = function() {  
                                var WhoSendTheMessage = self.loggedUser;
                                self.message.whoSendTheMessage.userId=WhoSendTheMessage;
                                console.log("The use is",contextService.userData.firstName+contextService.userData.lastName);
                                console.log("The userId is",WhoSendTheMessage);
                                self.message.messageBelongTo.conversationId=messageBelongTo; 
                                $scope.isAjax = true;
                                var url ="";
                                if($scope.value){
                                    url= contextService.getUrl("sendmessage")+"?loggedUser="+contextService.userData.userId+"&contactSelected="+contextService.selectedContact;

                                }else{
                                    url= contextService.getUrl("sendmessage")+"?loggedUser="+contextService.userData.userId+"&contactSelected="+contextService.selectedContact;

                                }  
                                ajaxService.post({
                                        url : url,
                                        data : angular.toJson(self.message),
                                        headers : {
                                            "Content-Type" : "application/json;charset=utf-8"
                                        },
                                        success : function(data) { 
                                            console.log("check question",data);
                                            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                                            //clear Text box
                                            $scope.value.push(data);
                                            self.message.content="";
                                            **$('.conversation-wrapper').scrollTop($('.conversation-wrapper').height());**
                                            $scope.isAjax = false;
                                            $scope.$apply();

                                        },
                                        error : function(data) {
                                            $log.log("project creation error block: ",data);
                                            $scope.isAjax = false;
                                            $scope.$apply();
                                        }
                                }); 
                            } 

                             //Receive Message
                             $scope.$on('messagereceived',function(event,msg){  
                                 if (!("Notification" in $window)) {
                                  console.log("called");
                              }
                                 else if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
                                       var options = {
                                           body: self.message.content,
                                           icon: "lib/app/img/user.jpg",

                                     };
                             var notification = new Notification(contextService.userData.firstName+contextService.userData.lastName,options);
                            }
                            else if (Notification.permission !== 'denied') {
                                  console.log("grantedsss");
                                     Notification.requestPermission(function (permission) {
                                  if (permission === "granted") {
                                          var options = {
                                            body: self.message.content,
                                            icon: "lib/app/img/user.jpg",

                                                 };
                              var notification = new Notification(contextService.userData.firstName+contextService.userData.lastName,options);
                                  }
                                });
                              }
                                 $scope.value.push(msg.message);  
                                 $scope.isAjax = false;
                                 $scope.$apply(); 
                             }); 

                        } ]);
                    return conversationController; 
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Give id to your bottom html element like this

```
<div class="conversation-new-message message-box" id="my-bottom-element">
```

and in controller add these lines when all your messages or other data has been loaded.

```
$location.hash('my-bottom-element');
$anchorScroll();
```

remember to include `$location` and `$anchorScroll` dependencies in your controller.

Comment: mudasser ajaz :Thanks ..but itss not Working

Comment: @Geetha where are you calling these line?

Comment: mudasser ajaz Thanks For ur reply..here with I have attached these line..but its not workajaxService.get({url : check, success :function(data) { $location.hash('my-bottom-element'); $anchorScroll();if( data.responseSuccess){  $log.log("Success!", angular.fromJson(data.result));
        if($scope.value.length !=0){
         messageBelongTo= $scope.value[0]['messageBelongTo']['conversationId'];
        }

Comment: As i told you need to call these lines when all your messages data is assigned to show on template.But you are calling it right at start of api response. Simple thing is it works when your screen fully ready with messages and has specific height. Then it goes to bottom.